# Pass an array of values as choices in choice field type symfony 2 form

Tags: forms, symfony

I'd appreciate some help with building a choice-type symfony 2 form. I have tried searching for answers and followed several leads but could not find exactly what I'm looking for.

The QuestionType class below is instantiated with four values (which are intended to serve as the choices in the form). However, when the form is rendered, the choices do not reflected the values that have been passed into the class. Any idea what went wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
class QuestionType extends AbstractType
{   
    private $foptionone;
    private $foptiontwo;
    private $foptionthree;
    private $foptionfour;

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {   
        $optionone=$this->foptionone;
        $optiontwo=$this->foptiontwo;
        $optionthree=$this->foptionthree;
        $optionfour=$this->foptionfour;

        $builder->add('sanswer','choice',array(
            'expanded'=>true,
            'choices'=>array(
                'a'=>$optionone,
                'b'=>$optiontwo,
                'c'=>$optionthree,
                'd'=>$optionfour)
            )
        );
    }

    public function _construct($qoptionone,$qoptiontwo,$qoptionthree,$qoptionfour)
    {
        $this->foptionone=$qoptionone;
        $this->foptiontwo=$qoptiontwo;
        $this->foptionthree=$qoptionthree;
        $this->foptionfour=$qoptionfour; 
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'questiontype';
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest you use an array for your variables. or even better use the `setDefaultOptions()` method to inject values not via constructor but via the `$options` array of your `buildForm` method. See the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/forms.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constructors have two underscores, not one:

```
public function __construct(...)
```

Your `_construct()` method is never getting called at all.

Comment: thanks a million! it was there all along, while i was looking all over the place!